# How to make the predicate ignore decimal point when using NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType?

Tags: ios, nspredicate

In my application I am using the predicate to filter the values in the array of dictionary.

Below is my array structure

```
    (     
    {
        Apr = "6070.3869";
        Feb = "9282.4067";
        Jan = "5367.6783";
        Jun = "7277.0928";
        Mar = "8036.672";
        May = "7677.0083";
    };
    {
        Apr = "8542.590200000001";
        Feb = "7471.3059";
        Jan = "8427.397999999999";
        Jun = "9138.6986";
        Mar = "7830.722";
        May = "9007.052600000001";
    };
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
)
```

I use table view to show the filtered list

If the user select the property(from jan,feb,mar,Apr),an operator(>,<,+) and enter an `int` value then I would show the filtered array

For example if he select `Apr` and enter 7000 and select < operator then I would show the array of dictionaries whose value for `Apr` key is less than 7000

I use below predicate to filter the array

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
///// filter is an instance of nsobject subclass ho;ding the value, key and operator
NSExpression *lhs = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:filter.name];
NSExpression *rhs = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:filter.values[0]];
predicate=[NSComparisonPredicate
                   predicateWithLeftExpression:lhs
                   rightExpression:rhs
                   modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                   type:[[filter operatorType] intValue]
                   options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

The above way is not working for NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType as the objects are floats

I am looking for a way to ignore the decimal points while filtering. Suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I do not completely understand what data are you filtering.

Comment: And what do you want to get?

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv I have added some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user needs `NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType` you can create compound predicate with two predicates that define upper and lower value limits. For lower limit you should use what user entered, for upper limit `userInput+1`.

```
NSExpression *lhs = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:filter.name];
NSExpression *rhs = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:filter.values[0]];
NSExpression *rhsUpper = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:(filter.values[0]+1)]; // assumed that you have number type here
NSPredicate *lowerBoundPredicate =
[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:lhs
                                   rightExpression:rhs
                                          modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                              type:NSGreaterThanOrEqualToPredicateOperatorType
                                           options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSPredicate *upperBoundPredicate =
[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:lhs
                                   rightExpression:rhsUpper
                                          modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                              type:NSLessThanPredicateOperatorType
                                           options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[lowerBoundPredicate, upperBoundPredicate]];
```

Compound predicate will return all decimals with integer part equal to user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore decimal point with the following regular expression for it:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K matches %@", filter.name, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@($|\.)", filter.values[0]]];
```

It works if you work with string values of decimals.

Comment: I get the error  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object 6070.3869.'    when checking against 6070 with key  'Apr'

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer values should be strings. Seems that they are numbers. You can try modify predicate to [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.stringValue matches %@", filter.name, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%@($|\.)", filter.values[0]]]; but I'm not sure if it works.